# Visualize change in test coverage with dotCover and TeamCity

Tags: c#, .net, teamcity, code-coverage, dotcover

Is there any way to visualize the change in test code coverage in dotCover/TeamCity between two build? Today we are able to see the overall change from the previous build (e.g. 70% -> 70.1%), but determining what lines of code tests has been added or removed for is a cumbersome process. A side by side view of the files that have different coverage would be really nice.

I prefer a solution for dotCover/TeamCity, but are open for other possibilities.

Comment: TeamCity does not have that out of the box, see this [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-13819).